# How to make tuples work in mvc 5, VS2017

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2017

My project was already on C#7.0:
[image]

and I already have Compilers and System.ValueTuple installed:
[image]

My view model WAS:

```
@model  IEnumerable<GHCOMvc.Models.PriorAddressModel>

<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>
      @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Address.Address)
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and it was all working.

When I changed it to this:

```
@using GHCOMvc.Controllers

@model  (IEnumerable<GHCOMvc.Models.PriorAddressModel> List, BaseController.Modes mode)

<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>
      @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Address.Address)
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

it gave the error:

> Error CS8059  Feature 'tuples' is not available in C# 6.  Please use
>   language version 7 or greater.

This isn't a core project so I don't have a Startup.cs file yet. I could add one to solve the problem, but I'm not clear on how to do that since this isn't a core project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know your specific issue, but I've ran in to similar before when compiling razor files. Check your target framework. Remember, razor is compiled *after* deployment. I bet you'll see your issue resolved if you rev your target framework.

Comment: It's set to 4.6.2. What change did you have in mind?

Comment: a version that contains c# 7. You need a toolset that supports the features you are using, since razor will be compiled at runtime. Target 4.7

Comment: When I went to Nuget to check for 4.7 (which I didn't even know existed yet, so thanks for that), I saw an Update notification I had not noticed before. It was published on 4/27/17. Anyway, that update fixed it without upgrading to 4.7. But I'll probably upgrade to 4.7 anyway because 7 > 6.

Answer (score 1):

Updating to `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform` `1.0.4` from `1.0.3` solved the issue for me:

[image]

**Note** I had to manually edit the csproj file to remove the references to `1.0.3` after I did this, to get it to build.

Then, in my view, I can do:

```
@model  (IEnumerable<GHCOMvc.Models.PriorAddressModel> list, BaseController.Modes mode)

<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>
      @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.list.FirstOrDefault().Address.Address)
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is a better answer than mine.

Comment: @ChiralMichael, I would not have found it without you :)